# Love2d GLSL shader script fails to retrieve texture_coords variable

Tags: lua, glsl, love2d, mandelbrot

Heello, everyone!
I've been trying to write a script that uses GLSL to render a Mandelbrot set, but something weird is happening.

I call the effect functio like this:

```
vec4 effect( vec4 color, Image texture, vec2 texture_coords, vec2 screen_coords){
```

But, when I try to use the texture_coords values, say, like this:

```
vec2 c = vec2((texture_coords[0]-WD/2)/100, (texture_coords[1]-HT/2)/100);
```

It returns the same value for every pixel; if, on the other hand, I use screen_coords instead, it works, but I'm affraid that if I drag the window around it might fuzz with the results.

Why am I unable to retrieve texture_coords?

More insight on the program and the problems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34659850/mandelbrot-set-through-shaders-in-glsl-with-love2d-renders-a-circle-not-a-fract)

---

UPDATE

I have reworked the code, now it looks like this:

```
vec4 effect( vec4 color, Image texture, vec2 texture_coords, vec2 window_coords)
{

    vec2 c = vec2( ( MinRe + window_coords[0] * ( MaxRe - MinRe ) / ( width + 1 ) ),
                   ( MaxIm - window_coords[1] * ( MaxIm - MinIm ) / ( height + 1 ) )
    );

    vec2 z = c;
    vec2 zn = vec2(0.0, 0.0);

    int n_iter = 0;

    while( (z[0]*z[0] + z[1]*z[1] < 4) && (n_iter < max_iter)) {
      zn[0] = z[0]*z[0] - z[1]*z[1] + c[0];
      zn[1] = 2* z[0]*z[1] + c[1];

      z[0] = zn[0];
      z[1] = zn[1];
      n_iter++;
}
```

Which works beautifully. But when I use texture_coords instead of window_coords, the code returns the same value to every pixel, despite the fact that the texture I'm using is the same size of the window.

Comment: `screen_coords` is incorrectly named; the actual name would be `window_coords`.

Comment: So it retrieves the coordinates relative to the window, right? And what is the texture_coords?

Comment: You know, Love2D [has a wiki.](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.newShader)

Comment: The wiki says it's actually the coordinates relative to the screen....

Comment: Yes. These are the same people who named them "screen_coords". Of course they think it's relative to the screen. My point is that it gives you a definition of what `texture_coords` means.

Comment: But it's somewhat misguiding, because my texture was the size of the window, and it didn't work -  so I figured the definition might be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that some drawable objects of `love.graphics` don't set any texture coordinate if you don't load an image. So, instead of using `draw.rectangle`, you should use a `Mesh`:

> A 2D polygon mesh used for drawing arbitrary textured shapes

In order to add a mesh object you can add to the load function:

```
function love.load()
    width, height = love.graphics.getDimensions( )
    local vertices = {
        {
            -- top-left corner 
            0, 0, -- position of the vertex
            0, 0, -- texture coordinate at the vertex position
            255, 0, 0, -- color of the vertex
        },
        {
            -- top-right corner 
            width, 0,
            1, 0, -- texture coordinates are in the range of [0, 1]
            0, 255, 0
        },
        {
            -- bottom-right corner 
            width, height,
            1, 1,
            0, 0, 255
        },
        {
            -- bottom-left corner 
            0, height,
            0, 1,
            255, 255, 0
        },
    }

    -- the Mesh DrawMode "fan" works well for 4-vertex Meshes.
    mesh = love.graphics.newMesh(vertices, "fan")

    -- ... other stuff here ...

end
```

and in the draw function:

```
function love.draw()
    -- ...
    love.graphics.draw(mesh,0,0)
    -- ...
end
```

The complete code, considering your previous question and my answer to that, adding some lines to manage the coordinate tranformations become:

```
function love.load()
    width, height = love.graphics.getDimensions( )
    local vertices = {
        {
            -- top-left corner 
            0, 0, -- position of the vertex
            0, 0, -- texture coordinate at the vertex position
            255, 0, 0, -- color of the vertex
        },
        {
            -- top-right corner 
            width, 0,
            1, 0, -- texture coordinates are in the range of [0, 1]
            0, 255, 0
        },
        {
            -- bottom-right corner 
            width, height,
            1, 1,
            0, 0, 255
        },
        {
            -- bottom-left corner 
            0, height,
            0, 1,
            255, 255, 0
        },
    }

    mesh = love.graphics.newMesh(vertices, "fan")

    GLSLShader = love.graphics.newShader[[
        vec4 black = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        vec4 white = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        extern int max_iter;
        extern vec2 size;
        extern vec2 left_top;

        vec4 clr(int n){
            if(n == max_iter){return black;}

            float m = float(n)/float(max_iter);
            float r = float(mod(n,256))/32;
            float g = float(128 - mod(n+64,127))/255;
            float b = float(127 + mod(n,64))/255;

            if (r > 1.0) {r = 1.0;}
            else{ 
                if(r<0){r = 0;}
            }

            if (g > 1.0) {g = 1.0;}
            else{
                if(g<0){g = 0;}
            }

            if (b > 1.0) {b = 1.0;}
            else{
                if(b<0){b = 0;}
            }
            return vec4(r, g, b, 1.0);
        }

        vec4 effect( vec4 color, Image texture, vec2 texture_coords, vec2 window_coords){  

            vec2 c = vec2(texture_coords[0]*size[0] + left_top[0],texture_coords[1]*size[1] - left_top[1]);
            vec2 z = vec2(0.0,0.0);
            vec2 zn = vec2(0.0,0.0);
            int n_iter = 0;
            while ( (z[0]*z[0] + z[1]*z[1] < 4) &&  (n_iter < max_iter) ) {
                zn[0] = z[0]*z[0] - z[1]*z[1] + c[0];
                zn[1] = 2*z[0]*z[1] + c[1];
                z[0] = zn[0];
                z[1] = zn[1];
                n_iter++;
            }
            return clr(n_iter);
        }
    ]]

end

function love.draw()

    center_x = -0.5
    center_y = 0.0
    size_x = 3
    size_y = size_x*height/width
    GLSLShader:send("left_top",{center_x-size_x*0.5,center_y+size_y*0.5})
    GLSLShader:send("size",{size_x,size_y})
    GLSLShader:sendInt("max_iter",1024)

    love.graphics.setShader(GLSLShader)
    love.graphics.draw(mesh,0,0)
    love.graphics.setShader()
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> But it's somewhat misguiding, because my texture was the size of the window, and it didn't work

Well, let's investigate that. You didn't exactly provide a lot of information, but let's look anyway.

```
(texture_coords[0]-WD/2)/100
```

What is that? Well, we know what `texture_coords` is. From the Love2D wiki:

> The location inside the texture to get pixel data from. Texture coordinates are usually normalized to the range of (0, 0) to (1, 1), with the top-left corner being (0, 0).

So you subtract from this texture coordinate `WD/2`. You didn't bother mentioning what that `WD` value was. But regardless, you divide the result by 100.

So, what exactly is `WD`? Let's see if algebra can help:

```
val = (texture_coords[0]-WD/2)/100
val * 100 = texture_coords[0] - WD / 2
(val * 100) - texture_coords[0] = -WD / 2
-2 * ((val * 100) - texture_coords[0]) = WD
```

So, what is `WD`? Well, from this equation, I can determine... nothing. This equation seems to be gibberish.

I'm guessing you intend for `WD` to mean "width" (seriously, it's *three more characters*; you couldn't type that out?). Presumably, the texture's width. If so... the equation remains *gibberish*.

You're taking a value that ranges from [0, 1], then subtracting half of the texture width from it. What does that mean? Why divide by 100? Since the texture width is probably much larger than the largest value from `texture_coords` (aka: 1), the result of this is going to be basically `-WD/200`.

And unless you're rendering to a floating-point image, that's going to get clamped to the valid color range: [0, 1]. So all your values come out to be the same color: black.

Since you're talking about Mandelbrot and so forth, I *suspect* you're trying to generate values on the range [-1, 1] or whatever. And your equation might do that... if `texture_coords` weren't *normalized texture coordinates* on the range [0, 1]. You know, exactly like the Wiki says they are.

If you want to turn texture coordinates into the [-1, 1] range, it's really much simpler. This is why we use *normalized* texture coordinates:

```
vec2 c = (2 * texture_coord) - 1; //Vector math is good.
```

If you want that to be the [-100, 100] range, just multiply the result by 100.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't provide enough information... I'm new to the forum and I'm trying to figure out how to properly write a post. In my last one I was told to provide less code, I can see this time I not only provided little code, but not nearly enough information. The code I provided was a later trial, but I have previously tried it like this `(texture_coords[0]-WD/2/100)`, but it didn't help...
I am also new to programming, and I have very little knowledge on proper coding practices...
Anyway, thanks for the help, I'll try to be more explicit with my future coding :)

Comment: My overall point was that the width doesn't matter. The width has already been factored out. It doesn't matter how big or how small you draw the quad; the texture coordinate will still go from 0 at the top/left to 1 at the bottom/right.

Comment: I made an update to the post. I've completely reworked the code, but it's still acting weird with texture_coords...

Comment: Man, I really do appreciate the help, but you really didn't need to be this rude... I understand perfectly these concepts, and if you check the update, I made it work with screen_coords, which is, theoretically, the same. And if you check Bob__'s answer, the problem is with how the drawables work, not my logic

Comment: "I made it work with screen_coords, which is, theoretically, the same." It's not the same. That's the point I'm trying to get across to you. The top-right part of your quad will have a window coordinate of (width, 0). But the ***texture coordinate*** will be (1, 0). That's what "normalized" means.

Comment: OK, I double checked the wiki and now I see what you meant. Sorry about the misunderstanding, but I really think you could have been a bit more polite. Thank you for the help